# Reading excel cells connected to api using c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have an xlsm file with tons of formulas in it, I am trying to read the values in the cell and create a new excel.

The problem I am having is with the cells that contains some kind of calculations, the cells are being fed by an api(bloomberg api), and when I try to read it's value I get "-2146826259". Following is how I am opening the excel file before reading it.

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    public List<ExcelData> GetTable(string sheetName, string rangeFrom, string rangeTo)
    {
        string testingExcel = @"C:\users\" + Environment.UserName+ @"\desktop\bbg1.xlsm";
        Application xlApp = new Application();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(testingExcel, Type.Missing, true,Type.Missing,"pwatch");

    }
```

[image]

I believe the problem could be the way my program is reading the file, the bloomberg api may not be loading when the program runs the file, so the cells are not getting a value and instead returning the error code. How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you have to evaluate the formulas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-run-excel-calculations-programmatically?view=vs-2019

Comment: -2146826259 is an error code, 0x800A07ED.  Google "excel error 2029" to learn more.